# Fixed Footer overlapping content?

Tags: html, css, position

I haven't been able to get this sidebar to position correctly without the footer over lapping it.

[image]

I have the footer absolute positioned on the bottom for a sticky footer, I know it removes it from the normal flow of the document when its absolutely positioned.

Anyone have an idea?

```html
<section class="sidebar col-md-6">
        <!--Popular Posts-->
        <!--TODO: Find a way to incorporate border design with text-->
        <div class="border-header">
            <p class="post-title">POPULAR POSTS</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="posts-border">My Adventure Through New York City</li>
                <li>Hiking The Pacific Crest Trail</li>
                <li>Explore the Breathtaking Antelope Canyon</li>
                <li>Fujifilm X100T Review: Best New Camera in 2016</li>
                <li>iPhone 6s Review: It Got Even Better</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!--Latest Reviews list -->

        <!-- Categories List -->
        <div class="border-header">
            <p class="post-title">CATEGORIES</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Business <span>(4)</span></li>
                <li>Reviews <span>(3)</span></li>
                <li>Science <span>(4)</span></li>
                <li>Technology <span>(4)</span></li>
                <li>Travel <span>(6)</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</section>
```

```css
//Sidebar

.sidebar {
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1;

}

    ul li {
        list-style: none;
    }


.posts-border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    width: 90%;
}

  .post-title {
        margin: -10px auto 10px auto; 
        text-align: center;
}

.border-header {
    border: 2px solid lightgray;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.spacer {
    margin: 200px;
}
```

Comment: It's not enough, please add your code too!

Comment: What about adding an equal amount of bottom margin to your main content element?

Comment: You need more code, what you have does not replicate your problem.

Comment: The project is built with handlebars, so i'm waiting on another to finish the main content section. They wanted me to work on the side bar, but i've been having some issues of positioning without it.

Comment: i have the footer code i could share, but the nav and main content sections have not been finished yet.

Comment: What the others said, it would be helpful if you put up either an outside link (like JsFiddle) so we can see the code and everything... Right now it's incomplete.  But something to point out, If you have an empty div container with clear: both   between the main container and the footer.  Also, to have a height: 100% for the main container.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for taking the time to help :)